# Xpath to find duplicates and non duplicates

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I would like to separate the following XML into those that are duplicates and those that are not duplicates on REGULAROUTGOINGSGUID

```
    <root>
    <REGULAROUTGOINGSCUSTOMER CUSTOMERNUMBER="1052461" CUSTOMERVERSIONNUMBER="4">
      <REGULAROUTGOINGS REGULAROUTGOINGSGUID="024EB2D43A7A4780B52D4B89CD7B1AF9" REGULAROUTGOINGSTYPE="60" AMOUNT="0" PAYMENTFREQUENCY="12" REGULAROUTGOINGSTYPE_TEXT="Ground rent and service charges" />
      <REGULAROUTGOINGS REGULAROUTGOINGSGUID="027DF40ECE06478DA9C8E62E916C9F58" REGULAROUTGOINGSTYPE="80" AMOUNT="100" PAYMENTFREQUENCY="12" REGULAROUTGOINGSTYPE_TEXT="Insurance premiums and pension contributions" />
      <REGULAROUTGOINGS REGULAROUTGOINGSGUID="1A59FB79940344D7B92B7CAEFAFD7769" REGULAROUTGOINGSTYPE="10" AMOUNT="50" PAYMENTFREQUENCY="12" REGULAROUTGOINGSTYPE_TEXT="Transport " />  
    </REGULAROUTGOINGSCUSTOMER>

    <REGULAROUTGOINGSCUSTOMER CUSTOMERNUMBER="1052462" CUSTOMERVERSIONNUMBER="3">
      <REGULAROUTGOINGS REGULAROUTGOINGSGUID="024EB2D43A7A4780B52D4B89CD7B1AF9" REGULAROUTGOINGSTYPE="60" AMOUNT="0" PAYMENTFREQUENCY="12" REGULAROUTGOINGSTYPE_TEXT="Ground rent and service charges" />
      <REGULAROUTGOINGS REGULAROUTGOINGSGUID="027DF40ECE06478DA9C8E62E916C9F58" REGULAROUTGOINGSTYPE="80" AMOUNT="100" PAYMENTFREQUENCY="12" REGULAROUTGOINGSTYPE_TEXT="Insurance premiums and pension contributions" />   
      <REGULAROUTGOINGS REGULAROUTGOINGSGUID="C2B379B9BA64466486CFB695CFC0297C" REGULAROUTGOINGSTYPE="20" AMOUNT="100" PAYMENTFREQUENCY="12" REGULAROUTGOINGSTYPE_TEXT="Food, alcohol and tobacco" />
    </REGULAROUTGOINGSCUSTOMER>
    </root>
```

So, in the following I am trying to get

```
<duplicates>
<REGULAROUTGOINGSCUSTOMER CUSTOMERNUMBER="1052461" CUSTOMERVERSIONNUMBER="4">
    <REGULAROUTGOINGS REGULAROUTGOINGSGUID="024EB2D43A7A4780B52D4B89CD7B1AF9" REGULAROUTGOINGSTYPE="60" AMOUNT="0" PAYMENTFREQUENCY="12" REGULAROUTGOINGSTYPE_TEXT="Ground rent and service charges" />
    <REGULAROUTGOINGS REGULAROUTGOINGSGUID="027DF40ECE06478DA9C8E62E916C9F58" REGULAROUTGOINGSTYPE="80" AMOUNT="100" PAYMENTFREQUENCY="12" REGULAROUTGOINGSTYPE_TEXT="Insurance premiums and pension contributions" />
</REGULAROUTGOINGSCUSTOMER>
<REGULAROUTGOINGSCUSTOMER CUSTOMERNUMBER="1052462" CUSTOMERVERSIONNUMBER="3">
    <REGULAROUTGOINGS REGULAROUTGOINGSGUID="024EB2D43A7A4780B52D4B89CD7B1AF9" REGULAROUTGOINGSTYPE="60" AMOUNT="0" PAYMENTFREQUENCY="12" REGULAROUTGOINGSTYPE_TEXT="Ground rent and service charges" />
    <REGULAROUTGOINGS REGULAROUTGOINGSGUID="027DF40ECE06478DA9C8E62E916C9F58" REGULAROUTGOINGSTYPE="80" AMOUNT="100" PAYMENTFREQUENCY="12" REGULAROUTGOINGSTYPE_TEXT="Insurance premiums and pension contributions" />   
</REGULAROUTGOINGSCUSTOMER>
</duplicates>
<unique>
<REGULAROUTGOINGSCUSTOMER CUSTOMERNUMBER="1052461" CUSTOMERVERSIONNUMBER="4">
    <REGULAROUTGOINGS REGULAROUTGOINGSGUID="1A59FB79940344D7B92B7CAEFAFD7769" REGULAROUTGOINGSTYPE="10" AMOUNT="50" PAYMENTFREQUENCY="12" REGULAROUTGOINGSTYPE_TEXT="Transport " />  
</REGULAROUTGOINGSCUSTOMER>
<REGULAROUTGOINGSCUSTOMER CUSTOMERNUMBER="1052462" CUSTOMERVERSIONNUMBER="3">
    <REGULAROUTGOINGS REGULAROUTGOINGSGUID="C2B379B9BA64466486CFB695CFC0297C" REGULAROUTGOINGSTYPE="20" AMOUNT="100" PAYMENTFREQUENCY="12" REGULAROUTGOINGSTYPE_TEXT="Food, alcohol and tobacco" />
</REGULAROUTGOINGSCUSTOMER>
</unique>
```

**EDIT**
XSL version 1.0 I believe

Comment: This is not possible with a single XPath 1.0 expression. If you are actually applying an XSLT stylesheet, please show your current XSLT code.

Comment: Please indicate XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="k" match="REGULAROUTGOINGS" use="@REGULAROUTGOINGSGUID" />

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:copy>
        <duplicates>
            <xsl:for-each select="REGULAROUTGOINGSCUSTOMER[REGULAROUTGOINGS[count(key('k', @REGULAROUTGOINGSGUID)) > 1]]">
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="REGULAROUTGOINGS[count(key('k', @REGULAROUTGOINGSGUID)) > 1]"/>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </duplicates>
        <unique>
            <xsl:for-each select="REGULAROUTGOINGSCUSTOMER[REGULAROUTGOINGS[count(key('k', @REGULAROUTGOINGSGUID)) = 1]]">
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="REGULAROUTGOINGS[count(key('k', @REGULAROUTGOINGSGUID)) = 1]"/>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </unique>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: It works exactly as specified. <xsl:key> was what I was missing